# Spring boot cloud data Datastore: Connection refused using docker compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to prepare infrastructure for local testing with DataStore. When I check localhost:8081 by my browser, where DataStore is hosted, then it return `ok`.

My docker-compose

```
services:

  application:
    image: openjdk:17
    ports:
      - 9000:8080 # HTTP
    volumes:
      - ${BASE_PATH:-.}/build/libs/application.jar
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/health-check" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 30
      start_period: 10s

  datastore:
    image: knarz/datastore-emulator
    ports:
      - 8081:8432
    environment:
      CONSISTENCY: 1 # If you omit this, the emulator will emulate eventual consistency.
```

My .yml file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      project-id: test-project
      datastore:
        host: localhost:8081
        emulator:
          enabled: true
          port: 8081
```

My method to get the data:

```
    private DatastoreTemplate datastoreTemplate;

    public Entity getEntity(String id) {
        return datastoreTemplate.findById(id, Entity.class);
    }
```

Exception is very generic:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: I/O error] with root cause","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: based on the code you show us on getting the data, I'm impressed it doesn't throw a NullPointerException

Comment: What does the `host: localhost:8081` setting do?  If it's a Spring property, it's telling the Spring application to connect to itself, not the other container, and that would explain the "connection refused" error.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.